# Thingsboard, errors while running install_dev_db.sh

Tags: node.js, maven, installation, thingsboard

I forked the thingsboard directory. Then I followed the instructions on the site:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/how-to-contribute/

My configuration:

.Ubuntu 16.04
.openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
.javac 1.8.0_151
.Apache Maven 3.3.9
.Node v8.0.0
.npm 5.6.0

I entered the command lines:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests  
cd ${TB_WORK_DIR}/application/target/bin/install  
chmod +x install_dev_db.sh  
./install_dev_db.sh
```

I get the following message:
(I didn't find any issue that would help until then)

```
 ===================================================
 :: ThingsBoard ::       (v1.4.0-SNAPSHOT)
 ===================================================

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (hsqldb.db.HSQLDB616AE4A249.ENGINE).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: file input/output error: /tmp/thingsboardDb.log
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:340)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:521)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output error: /tmp/thingsboardDb.log
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.openLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Starting ThingsBoard Installation...
Installing DataBase schema...
Installing SQL DataBase schema...
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
java.sql.SQLException: file input/output error: /tmp/thingsboardDb.log
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlDatabaseSchemaService.createDatabaseSchema(SqlDatabaseSchemaService.java:60)
    at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:118)
    at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:521)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output error: /tmp/thingsboardDb.log
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.openLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
ThingsBoard DB installation failed!
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your log4j properly running and set in the PATH etc? The warning has a link to the old site strangely enough, new site: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html

Comment: The problem was that I had to enter the following command line:  sudo rm -rf /tmp/thingsboardDb*

Comment: Nice, could you please add that as the answer and accept it as such?